# how long will it cost when I convert a mongodb standalone node to replicaset?

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

There is running a single node mongodb server, and about 28,000,000 documents,
now I want to convert it to replicaSet, 
but I am not sure if it will cost too much time?
and also if the db will works during the initialize process?

Comment: what do you mean by 2800w?

Comment: sorry, I mean 28 millions

Answer (score 0):

If you config right, I mean avoid [mongodb-primary-replica-becomes-secondary-if-secondary-fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650563/mongodb-primary-replica-becomes-secondary-if-secondary-fails/35650861#35650861), it will works during the initialize process. The initialization time depends on network bandwidth and cost of index building.

Answer (score 0):

Once your primary is up and ready, documents will be accessible as primary will hold all current documents, But secondaries will take a while to sync data from primary.

See my answer to another related post [MongoDB hidden secondary stuck in startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36160317/mongodb-hidden-secondary-stuck-in-startup/36161361#36161361), I'm sure it will help you.